Isometric Function from Plane
User @TMTM26 has posted a question about isometry that he asked how to prove the function:
$\alpha: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R^2}, \alpha(x,y) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(x-y,x+y\right)$ to be isometric. The post was closed almost immediately, and I don't have a chance to post my answer. So I post it here.I will provide my answer in the answer column.

Let $x = (x_1,x_2), y = (y_1,y_2)$. We have: $\text{dist}(\alpha(x),\alpha(y))= \text{dist}\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(x_1-x_2,x_1+x_2\right),\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(y_1-y_2,y_1+y_2\right)\right)=\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{2}((x_1-y_1)-(x_2-y_2))^2+\dfrac{1}{2}((x_1-y_1)+(x_2-y_2))^2}=\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2}=\text{dist}(x,y)$. This proves $\alpha$ isometric.

If we identify $\Bbb R^2$ with $\Bbb C$ by $z=x+iy$, the map $\alpha$ corresponds to the map $f:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ given by $f(z)=e^{\frac\pi 4 i}z$. Then, the distance between two points on $\Bbb R^2$ corresponds to the magnitude of the difference of complex numbers and we have
$$||f(z_1)-f(z_2)||=||e^{\frac\pi 4 i}z_1-e^{\frac\pi 4 i}z_2||=
||z_1-z_2||e^{\frac\pi 4 i}||=||z_1-z_2||
$$
since $||e^{\theta i}||=1$. Hence, $\alpha$ is isometry.
